# Converting Oracle Hierarchical Query to MariaDB

Tags: oracle, mariadb, hierarchical-data

I am working on converting oracle queries to maria db. There is no hierarchical queries like "start with...connect by..." in MariaDB. So I had to create queries similar to "start with... " But it looks hard. Can you guys help me?

```
SELECT *
       FROM
           (SELECT T2.JOB_TYPE, 
                   T2.COMPONENT_TYPE,
                   T1.POOL_SEQ,
                   FN_GET_CODE_VALUE('componenttype',T2.COMPONENT_TYPE) AS COMPONENT_TYPE_NM,
                   MIN(T1.WORKFLOW_SEQ)WORKFLOW_SEQ,
                   MIN(T1.UPPER_WORKFLOW_SEQ)UPPER_WORKFLOW_SEQ,
                   MAX(T1.DEFAULT_JOB_SEQ)DEFAULT_JOB_SEQ,
                   T1.WORKFLOW_TYPE,
                   /*   MAX(T1.WORKFLOW_TYPE)WORKFLOW_TYPE, */
                   COUNT(CASE T1.JOB_STATE WHEN '01' THEN 1 END)STATE_01_CNT,
                   COUNT(CASE T1.JOB_STATE WHEN '02' THEN 1 END)STATE_02_CNT,
                   COUNT(CASE T1.JOB_STATE WHEN '03' THEN 1 END)STATE_03_CNT,
                   COUNT(CASE T1.JOB_RESULT WHEN '20' THEN 1 END)ERCNT,
                   COUNT(CASE T1.JOB_RESULT WHEN '10' THEN 1 END)END_CNT,
                   COUNT(*)TOT_CNT
                   /*   ,MAX(T1.POOL_SEQ)POOL_SEQ   */
              FROM JOB_TBL T1,
                   SERVER_POOL_TBL T2
             WHERE T1.POOL_SEQ =  T2.POOL_SEQ

          )T
  START WITH UPPER_WORKFLOW_SEQ IS NULL
CONNECT BY UPPER_WORKFLOW_SEQ = PRIOR WORKFLOW_SEQ
```

Comment: I don't think Maria DB has an equivalent of `connect by`.. though you can implement it in a procedure or function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Recirsive CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/). `connect by` is Oracle proprietary extension, introduced before CTEs were "invented". Recursive CTEs are also more generic.